# why do these two boolen expression give me different results?

Tags: arrays, c, boolean

I am trying to compare elements of two arrays according their order, for example:

```
bool compare_arr(int *a, int *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) // !!!
        {
            return false; // !!!
        }
    }
    return true; // !!!
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {2, 0, 4};
    int b[] = {2, 3, 4};
    if (compare_arr(a, b))
    {
        printf("arr elements are equal in order\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("arr elements are different in order\n");
    }
}
```

It gives me `arr elements are different in order` (right)

But if I change boolean expression:

```
bool compare_arr(int *a, int *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == b[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It gives me `arr elements are equal in order` (wrong)

In my opinion, both bool expresion has the same logic, but as you can see, have different results.

Comment: The second will return true right away if  encountering two equal  elements (even the first ones). And will return false only if *all of them* are unequal. Definitely not what you want.

Comment: In this case, a debugger would be gold!

Answer (score 2):

Unroll the loops and you will see.

The first one is equivalent to:

```cpp
bool compare_arr(int *a, int *b)
{
    return !(a[0] != b[0]) && !(a[1] != b[1]) && ...
}
```

or simplified:

```cpp
bool compare_arr(int *a, int *b)
{
    return a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && ...
}
```

because you need to pass *all* iterations to return true.

The second one is equivalent to:

```cpp
bool compare_arr(int *a, int *b)
{
    return a[0] == b[0] || a[1] == b[1] || ...
}
```

because you can return true in *any* of the iterations.

In short, the first function means "for all pairs, elements are equal" while the second one means "for at least one pair, elements are equal".